# Microsoft Office Outlook cannot provide form scripting support

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I have just installed Office 2007 on a Server 2003 machine, but I'm getting the following error when I'm starting Outlook (clicking OK 6 times gets rid of the message) -

[image]

I first followed the advise on the error itself, but every feature of Outlook was already set to 'Run from My Computer'.

Next I searched the web, and I found a [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=302003) that suggested copying the `OUTLVBS.dll` file from a non-terminal services install of Office to the `Office11` folder. I tried this (and also copying it to `Office12`, as that is where I copied it from), but to no avail.

Can anyone kindly suggest how I can fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that `OUTLVBS.DLL` was not installed. Essentially, I had to register the `VBS` resource so that `OUTLVBS.DLL` is installed from the CD (with the CD in the drive of course).

Once the CD is inserted, run this command -

> msiexec /i {90120000-0012-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE} ADDLOCAL=OutlookVBScript /qb

- Note that **90120000-0012-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE** is the GUID for **Office 2007 Standard**, and apparently other versions may have a different GUID. [This post](http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/258085-microsoft-office-outlook-cannot-provide-form-scripting-support-solved/) explains how uses can find the correct GUID if required